# How to construct a tree given each degrees maximum degree?

Tags: graph

I have a "maximum" degree sequences of graph vertices. Now I want to construct a tree where every nodes have "AT most" coresponding maximum degree.

For example, if my maximum degree sequence is A = [3,4,2,1,4,3] then I want to make a tree of 6 vertices and each vertex having "maximum degree" corresponding to its value in A.

So far I tried with vertex coloring, but not able to get a tree, rather sometimes I get a graph having a cycle in it.

Comment: A vertex has some precise given degree (number of edges connected from it), it does not have a "maximum degree". Or do you mean you can interpret "4" to a 2-degree vertex ?

Comment: Does the order in your list matters somehow for you generation ? I mean, if sequence [4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1] is given instead of your example  [3,4,2,1,4,3], could it give you the same tree ?

Comment: @Pac0 I know degree of a node is defined and cannot have maximum or minimum. By my statement what I meant is while constructing the tree, any particular nodes degree should not be "more" than its maximum allowed degree. For example, node 0 cannot have more than degree A[0], and node 3 cannot have more degree than A[3]. Order matters as they define each nodes respective maximum degree allowed.

Comment: But if I read this as 'there must be 2 nodes with max degree 4 each, 2 nodes with max degree 3 each, 1 node with max degree 2 and 1 node with degree 1" --> this interpretation is correct, whatever the order of the sequence given, right ?

Comment: @Pac0 there is order constraint. And that's why i feel stuck.

Comment: but I still don't understand what the order constraint is. How the tree from [4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1] is supposed to be differrent from the one with  [3,4,2,1,4,3] ?

Comment: Each specific node has some associated cost. So nodes can afford to have more edges and some not. That's the reason why the order matters here.

Comment: How the tree from [4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1] is supposed to be different from the one with [3,4,2,1,4,3] ?

Comment: Here node 0 that is A[0] has max degree 4. If each edge cost 10 then this nodes cost is 40 in the first case.

In the second case, it will be 3*10 = 30. So, a degree of 3 is preferred more than of 4. Point is it's not just 2 nodes of 4 degrees, it is specific node 0 having maximum degree 4.

Comment: I still think that the order given is not relevant *for the overall resulting tree* .

Comment: ok, if so could you please let me know your logic of creating the tree. Thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14100/condition-on-degrees-for-existence-of-a-tree).

Answer (score 1):

First let's recall an important fact on degrees of a tree with `n` vertices : total of degrees is always `2*(n-1)` . The converse is also true, a graph is a tree if its degree sum is `2*(n-1)`. And actually, any sequence of natural numbers that gives `2*(n-1)` could represent the degrees of a tree.

So the general algorithm for your problem should look like this :

1. Reduce the "max degrees" list to an actual "degree list".
2. From the list of degrees, use any graph construction algorithm. The resulting graph *will* be a tree because of the sum of degrees.

Note that : there might be several possibilities, but at the end, **the total edge cost will be the same**, `(n-1) * cost of one edge` , whatever is the resulting tree!

---

Example :

take sequence  A = [3,4,2,1,4,3] . Total is 17. We should have 10 to have a tree.

Let's reduce by one every degree greater than one.

It gives : B = [2,3,1,1,3,2]. Total is 12.

Let's reduce by one the 2 first degreed greater by one we find :

It gives : C = [1,2,1,1,3,2]. Total is 10. This is the degree list of a tree.

Let's draw it.

Start by the degree one vertices (there must be at least 2 of them), then append by increasing order of degrees :

```
1--
1--
1--

1--2--
1--2--
1--

1--2--\
1--2---3
1-----/
```

Sorry my ASCII ART skills are not the best.

To be more specific : we whould try to link "greedily" n-1 vertices on the right of the diagram with any left vertex of degree n. Excepted for the last one which should link whatever is remaining.

example for [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

```
1--
1--
1--
1--
1--

1---3
1--/
1---3
1--/
1--

1---3-\
1--/   \
1---3---3
1--/   /
1-----/
```